# How to trigger a modal in the parent component based on the a button clicked from child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have :

- panelHeader.vue (child component)
- index.vue (my main list view is the parent)

---

`panelHeader.vue`

```
<template>
    <v-row>
        <div class="panelHeader">
            <v-card>
                <v-card-title>{{ name }}</v-card-title>
                <v-card-subtitle>{{ subTitle }}</v-card-subtitle>
            </v-card>
            <v-btn @click="btnClicked"> Click </v-btn>
        </div>
    </v-row>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        icon: String,
        name: String,
        subTitle: String
    },
    methods: {
        btnClicked() {
            this.$emit('btnClicked', true)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

When clicked, I want to trigger a modal on my main `index.vue`

So I did that

```
<v-dialog @btnClicked="showModal" width="500px" class="d-flex justify-center">
    <v-card>
        <v-card-text> Any texts...</v-card-text>
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>
```

Is this wrong?

```
@btnClicked="showModal"
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into an answer added by me ? Hope that will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change some things over here:

```js
<v-dialog v-if="showModal" @btnClicked="handleShowModal" width="500px" class="d-flex justify-center">
    <v-card>
        <v-card-text> Any texts...</v-card-text>
    </v-card>
</v-dialog>

data() {
    return {
        showModal = false
    }

}

methods: {
    handleShowModal(e) {
        this.showModal = e
    }
}
```

Comment: oh is it ? I thought we need to pass the information from the button from the child component to the parent component.

Comment: Well, you are passing `true` as information from your child component using `this.$emit('btnClicked', true)`

Answer (score 1):

***Observations :***

- Capture emit event inside the `<child-component>` element instead of parent element `<v-dialog>`
- Emit event name should be hyphen separated `btn-clicked` instead of `camelCase`
- `v-dialog` component should contain `v-model` directive/attribute to assign the emitted value.

Live Demo **:**

```js
Vue.component('panelheader', {
  props: ['name'],
  template: `<div class="panelHeader">
<v-card>
<v-card-title>{{ name }}</v-card-title>
</v-card>
<v-btn @click="btnClicked"> Click </v-btn>
</div>`,
  methods: {
    btnClicked() {
      this.$emit('btn-clicked', true)
    }
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: function () {
    return {
      dialog: false,
      panelName: 'Hello Vue'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showModal(e) {
      this.dialog = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.0.2/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-dialog width="500px" v-model="dialog">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-text> Any texts...</v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
    <panelheader v-on:btn-clicked="showModal" :name="panelName"></panelheader>
  </v-app>
</div>
```